# why host video on Amazon S3 instead of hostgator

Tags: amazon-s3

i have some videos- flash that i want to host on my blog. should i use Amazon S3 or can i host it using my hostgator account. any ideas

Answer (score 3):

Within Amazon S3 you pay for the bandwidth and disk space that you use. With hostgator they say unlimited bandwidth and disk space, but if you read the [terms of service](http://www.hostgator.com/tos/tos.php) they say they give you a monthly limit on bandwidth. So if you're exceeding your limit I would move your files to S3.

Comment: Adding to this, it would mean that you can take advantage of CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be telling to do the math on how large your video is vs. how many full downloads you expect per month. If the numbers look good, you could probably stick with your Hostgator account. If it looks as if your estimates will approach the ceiling set by Hostgator, perhaps leading to overages, you should go with S3. S3 also some some nice reporting tools.